# How to define Array[] style initializer?

Tags: ruby, initialization

A ruby array can be initialized using:

```
irb(main):01:0> Array[1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I emulate this behavior in my own class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the public `[](*args)` class method.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
  def self.[] *args
    new *args
  end
  # ...
end
```